# Python os cannot get path to Desktop on One Drive

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I am trying to get user's path to Desktop by using the following code:

```
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop') 

d = datetime.datetime.today()

newpath = desktop + '\\New_folder' + str(d.day) + '_' + str(d.month) + '_' + str(d.year)
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

print('Desktop folder created:  ' + newpath)
```

For most users that works, but I recently got a case of a user who has everything on One Drive and their path is: 'C:\Users\User1\OneDrive - CompanyName\Desktop'.

For these users, the script fails with this message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the file specified 'C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\New_folder_16_3_2020
```

How do I point python to their actual Desktop path, so that I can then work with that folder?

Comment: OneDrive does a lot of magic. You see all the files in your OneDrive folder but they aren't actually there. When you want to open a video you will first download the video from OneDrive cloud and then it is actually there.  
The OneDrive folder looks like a normal Windows folder but it's not. If you want to support OneDrive you will have to interface with the OneDrive API.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74006573/python-get-desktop-path-directly-on-windows You can find the answer here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suspect the reason for yours is that, make sure that you're accessing the directory through OneDrive instead of following the path to the desktop immediately from the user. So instead of this

```
C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\New_folder_16_3_2020
```

it would be something like this

```
C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\OneDrive\\New_folder_16_3_2020
```

I would recommend you to add a try/catch statement that if fails prepends/appends the `oneDrive` keyword to the path.

Comment: Thanks, I did not actually try this. A more systemic solution would be prefered but since there is only one such user, this will do!

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with glob using a generic statement that will work for onedrive users and then check for non-onedrive users, something like this:

```
import os
from glob import glob

# assume onedrive is present, desktop will be one layer below
# something like "C:/Users/username/Onedrive - company name/Desktop"

desktop = glob(os.path.expanduser("~\\*\\Desktop"))

# if no Onedrive, then glob returns empty list revert to standard Desktop
# location: i.e. "C:/Users/username/Desktop
if len(desktop) == 0:
    desktop = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop")
```