# How to check first if directory exists before typing characters using python type_keys() then pressing send using send_keys?

Tags: python, onedrive, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto. This is my initial code when I type a specific directory then immediately press send using send_keys

```
dlg.type_keys(r'start "" "Downloads"', with_spaces=True)
send_keys("{ENTER}")
```

My problem is what if OneDrive directory is available and it is the directory being used instead of my code above. Sample OneDrive directory goes like this:

```
dlg.type_keys(r'start "" "OneDrive\Downloads"', with_spaces=True)
send_keys("{ENTER}")
```

How can I first check if the directory is available or not, before typing in the directory and pressing send? How should I add a checking for the two codes above

UPDATE:
I TRIED LIKE THIS BUT IT DOES NOT WORK

```
if os.path.exists("OneDrive"):
    dlg.type_keys(r'start "" "OneDrive\Downloads"', with_spaces=True)
else:
    dlg.type_keys(r'start "" "Downloads"', with_spaces=True)
send_keys("{ENTER}")
```

My issue is similar with this one: [Python os cannot get path to Desktop on One Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60742419/python-os-cannot-get-path-to-desktop-on-one-drive)
but it did not get a concrete answer

Comment: I don't know about pywinauto, but the problem might be that `os.path.exists("OneDrive")` checks for existence of "OneDrive" within the working directory _of the Python script_, which is often the directory where the .py file is located and may be different from the directory which the `start ...` command is relative to

Comment: You got a point, I'll look into it later! Thank you!